# Arrange each character of the word in alphabetical order and words should be arranged in ascending order depending on its character count

Tags: javascript

**Write a function which takes a sentence as an input and output a sorted sentence.**

> 1.Each character of the word should be arranged in alphabetical order
>
> 2.Words should be arranged in ascending order depending on its character count

Note: - Word only can have lowercase letters

> Example :
>
> Inputs str = "she lives with him in a small apartment"
>
> Output = "a in ehs him hitw eilsv allms aaemnprtt"

My Progress So Far :

```
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  return str.split("").sort().join("");

}

makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment");
```

Comment: So, what's your question? Is it "Solve this for me" or you have any specific problem?

Comment: I got this as a one of the questions after applying for an internship at a company, I'm not very good at handling string.
I know that I'm supposed to use the sort() function but can't use it properly.

Comment: I want to learn how to use the sort function so that I can do these kinds of things in the future.

Comment: Hmm, i think this kind of question is better to try and solve on your own. Giving you a answer fells like cheating. Instead try and write at least something and we will try to help you correct your misstake if you encounter any error

Comment: `return str.split("").sort().join("");`
The way I see this is firstly you seperate the words with the split() function,
then you sort the words according to alphabetical order, then join them back ?

Comment: Don't want to give you the full answer, but split first on space `" "` and sort each word by the length, the `sort()` function can also take a comparison function with current/next value `str.split(" ").sort(fn)` then you will get an array back. before joining it to a single string use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to sort each char of each word and then lastly you can join the final array back with `.join(" ")`

Comment: MDN is a good page to find out how things works: have a look at some sort comparison here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function makeAlphabetSentenceSort(str) {
  var spaceSplit = str.split(' ');  
  spaceSplit.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.length - b.length;
  });

  function alphaSort(b){

    var x = b.split("");
    return x.sort().join("");

  }

  var output = "";
  for(var i = 0; i <= spaceSplit.length - 1; i++){
     output += alphaSort(spaceSplit[i]) + " ";
  }
  return output.trim();
}

makeAlphabetSentenceSort("she lives with him in a small apartment");
```